# Correct Join for sending Daily Notification Emails (PHP, Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building a daily notification email script.

I need to join 4 tables to the user table, and I need the user_email in every `while ($user = mysql_fetch_array($result)){`  statement.

I was able to get this to work with an outer join with 1 table, but I'm having trouble getting the syntax to perform the objective with a different table to join after the first table join runs out of results.  I want the mysql query to grab the contents until the first join runs out (for each user), and then start displaying data for the second join query (all executing in a while loop).  Is this possible, if so, what would be the syntax?

Existing Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM users
    OUTER JOIN contest_entries ON contest_entries.email = users.email ";    

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

The second query I want to attach is getting all new contests.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM contests";
```

So for each user, I would want to display every `contest_entries` field that is applicable to them, and then every `contests` field that is applicable to them.

Note:  In order to save processing power/time, I will probably just store all contests in a string and then add them to each email later, but I want to use this an example to find the correct multiple joining technique.

Comment: The is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` in SQL. But not (just)  `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @Bob: You don't suppose that someone will just guess what your 4 tables structure is, do you?

Comment: I thought stackoverflow users were good guessers.  Seriously, though - I really want to see an example for these three so I have an idea how to apply it to the rest of the tables.

Comment: What criteria is used to select which `contests` are applicable to a user?  Your comments in the answer below make it sound like you want **all** contests, while the question describes displaying **specific** contests.

Comment: @Bob: As @Thomas asked and you stated: "***I would want to display every contests field that is applicable to them***. How is that application (relation) done?

Comment: Sorry, vague question issue here.  all new contests above would be every contest that started in the last 24 hours.  There's also other queries I'll be adding like new comments on a contest you own and new submissions on a contest you own - but I'll figure that out after I understand the join structures needed

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM users
          LEFT JOIN contest_entries
            ON contest_entries.email = users.email
          JOIN contests
            ON contests.id = contest_entries.contestid
        ORDER BY users.email                 --- or whatever other order you need
               , contest.id ";
```

You can then iterate in PHP over the result set which is already ordered (and grouped) by users and contests.

---

If you haven't (yet) any way to relate `users` with `contests`, I guess you are still designing your application and database structure. You can use this to show users related to all contests and then experiment applying conditions in the `WHERE` clause.:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 

        FROM users
          LEFT JOIN contest_entries
            ON contest_entries.email = users.email
          CROSS JOIN contests

        WHERE ( contests.started >= NOW() - interval 3 day )   --- new contests
          AND ( users.age <= contests.agelimit )               
          AND ( some other condition )                         

        ORDER BY users.email                 --- or whatever other order you need
               , contest.id " ;
```

Comment: Hey - it's almost there, except there's no key for joining contests, we're getting all contests

Comment: Well, then I can't guess no more. Post the tables and their fields and we can suggest adding or altering the structure. There should be a common field in `contests` and `contest_enties` so the two tables can be related in queries.

Comment: This join syntax limits the contests.  It should join all contests - maybe join isn't the correct syntax?

Comment: Yes, this is the (usually wanted) behaviour. You can show all users and contests combinations in one query but that can be inefficient, especially since you want tmanipulate the data later in PHP. You could just have the two queries and combine the data in your application code.

Comment: Instead of `JOIN contests
            ON ...` you could have `CROSS JOIN contests` to show all such combinations